# Create ordered Array from Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

This is a fundamental thing that I should know but don't know at a deep level and therefore find confusing. Dictionaries seem to be unordered list of keys and values.  I want to create an ordered list of keys and values so that I can sort and otherwise keep track of order.  I think this means I have to convert the dictionary into a multi-dimensional Array that has the key and value and also an index value ie 0,1,2,3 etc.

If my dictionary looks like the following:

```
var myScores = [String: Float]()
myScores = ["player1":22,"player2":33]
```

How do I convert it into an `Array` where player1:22 is the first element and player2:33 is the second element?

**Edit:**

Alternative without creating struct is to create an empty array of dictionaries in the form of your dictionary and then append your dictionary to the array.

```
var myArray = [[String: Float]]()//note double brackets
propArray.append(myScores)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an array of structs.

```
struct Score {
    let playerName: String
    let score: Int
}

let scores = [Score(playerName: "player1", score: 22),
              Score(playerName: "player2", score: 33),
             ]
let sortedScores = scores.sorted(by: { $0.playerName < $1.playerName })
```

To get key-value pairs out of a dictionary is straightforward, though it forces you to work with tuples, which are not a particularly friendly type. Even so, it's done this way:

```
let sortedScores = myScores.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
```

That will create:

```
[(key: "player1", value: 22.0), (key: "player2", value: 33.0)]
```

Or

```
for (name, score) in myScores.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }) {
    print(name, score)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the much better solution.

Comment: This makes sense a way to do it from scratch.  Is there any shortcut to creating an array if I already have a fully populated dictionary, something like let arrayFromDic = Array(dic.values.map{ $0 }) (that also preserves keys)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the dictionary as-is. One possible solution is to create an array that contains just the keys in the desired order. Then you can iterate the key array and access the elements of the dictionary.

```
var myScores: [String:Float] = ["player1":22, "player2":33]
var myPlayers = myScores.keys.sorted()

for player in myPlayers {
    let score = myScores[player]
}
```

This works when you want to show the data in some particular order, such as in a table view.